# Add D3 visualization to leaflet popup

Tags: r, d3.js, leaflet

I'm using R and leaflet to create a map.

```r
leaflet() %>%
  addTiles() %>%  # Add default OpenStreetMap map tiles
  addMarkers(lng=174.768, lat=-36.852, popup="The birthplace of R")
```

Then I have a D3 visualization created in HTML that I would like to add to the popup. What is the easiest way to do this? I have tried to save the HTML as a file and then add it with `htmltools`, `htmlwidgets`, `leafpop` but with no success.

Anyone have an idea?

Below is the snippet of the D3 viz.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v7.min.js"></script>
  <style>
    .timeline {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100px;
      background-color: #f0f0f0;
    }
    .graph-container {
      width: 200px;
      height: 120px;
    }
    .line {
      stroke: #d0d0d0;
      stroke-width: 2;
    }
    .phase-line {
      stroke: #d0d0d0;
      stroke-width: 2;
    }
    .dot {
      fill: #3498db;
    }
    
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="timeline"></div>

  <script>
    const phases = [
      { name: "Phase 1", position: 10 },
      { name: "Phase 2", position: 30 },
      { name: "Phase 3", position: 50 },
      { name: "Phase 4", position: 70 },
      { name: "Phase 5", position: 90 }
    ];

    const selectedPhase = "Phase 4";

    const timelineContainer = d3.select(".timeline");

    const svg = timelineContainer.append("svg")
      .attr("width", "100%")
      .attr("height", "100%");

    // Add horizontal line
    svg.append("line")
      .attr("class", "line")
      .attr("x1", 0)
      .attr("y1", "50%")
      .attr("x2", "100%")
      .attr("y2", "50%");

    const phaseLines = svg.selectAll(".phase-line")
      .data(phases)
      .enter()
      .append("line")
      .attr("class", "phase-line")
      .attr("x1", d => d.position + "%")
      .attr("y1", "40%")
      .attr("x2", d => d.position + "%")
      .attr("y2", "60%");

    const phaseLabels = svg.selectAll(".phase-label")
      .data(phases)
      .enter()
      .append("text")
      .attr("class", "phase-label")
      .attr("x", d => d.position + "%")
      .attr("y", "90%")
      .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
      .text(d => d.name);
      
       const dot = svg.append("circle")
      .attr("class", "dot")
      .attr("cx", d => {
        const selected = phases.find(phase => phase.name === selectedPhase);
        return selected ? selected.position + "%" : 0;
      })
      .attr("cy", "50%")
      .attr("r", 5);

  </script>
</body>
</html>
```